# Using single object field in object distructuring

Tags: javascript

I want to merge one field from `q = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}` with object `w = {a: 111, b: 111, c: 111}` by object destructuring, but I can't do neither `{...w, q.a}`, nor `{...w, q[a]}`.

I want to get `{a: 1, b: 111, c: 111}`.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify a key:

```
{...w, a: q.a }
```

(And this is *object spreading*, not *destructuring*)

Comment: Object cannot have two keys with same name `a`

Comment: @ankit literals can contain the same key twice.

Comment: @JonasW., not in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let q = {a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}
let w = {a: 111, b: 111, c: 111}

let z = {...q, newKey: w.a}
console.log(z)
```

You were almost there but you missing a key while appending the new property